# python iterate over sql query for select statement

Tags: python-3.x

How do i execute select statement for all the 4 id's that is 10, 20, 34 and 1 and would expect the result to be in a list

```
import pymysql
import json

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', 
db='mydb', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

cursor = conn.cursor()

select_query = "select * from users where id = "
ids = ["10", "20", "34", "1"]
for x in ids:
    var = select_query + x
    # print(var)
    print(list(cursor.execute(var)))
```

Comment: What results are you currently getting? How are the desired results different from that?

Comment: getting error - TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. not sure where i went wrong

Comment: The stack trace will tell you the line at which the error occurred. Which line was it, in this case?

Comment: stack trace - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\for.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(list(cursor.execute(var)))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [PyMySQL docs](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute), the `cursor.execute()` function returns an `int`, which is why your error is showing up. You'll want to call that, then use one of the [fetch functions](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.fetchall) to actually return the results

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='',
                       db='mydb', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

cursor = conn.cursor()

select_query = "select * from users where id = "
ids = ["10", "20", "34", "1"]
for x in ids:
    var = select_query + x
    # print(var)
    cursor.execute(var)
    print(list(cursor.fetchall()))
```

or, if you want all of the results in one list:

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='',
                       db='mydb', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

cursor = conn.cursor()

lst = []

select_query = "select * from users where id = "
ids = ["10", "20", "34", "1"]
for x in ids:
    var = select_query + x
    # print(var)
    cursor.execute(var)
    lst.extend(cursor.fetchall())

print(lst)
```

or as a dictionary

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='',
                       db='mydb', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

cursor = conn.cursor()

results = {}

select_query = "select * from users where id = "
ids = ["10", "20", "34", "1"]
for x in ids:
    var = select_query + x
    # print(var)
    cursor.execute(var)
    results[x] = list(cursor.fetchall())

print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to typecast x to str

```
import pymysql
import json

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', 
db='mydb', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

cursor = conn.cursor()

select_query = "select * from users where id = "
ids = ["10", "20", "34", "1"]
for x in ids:
    var = select_query + str(x)    # here
    # print(var)
    print(list(cursor.execute(var)))
```

Comment: getting same error - stack trace. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\for.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(list(cursor.execute(var)))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable